# How can I set the browsers locale in a robotframework test

Tags: localization, robotframework

I would like to start a browser with a specific locale settings like fr

I've try with
Open Browser  ${TEST_ENV}/${TEST_APP}  Chrome  options=add_argument(locale=fr)

but is not working.
Please could you help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have this example, only for Chrome (it has more things than you ask):

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     I have a challenge
...               I’m running Chrome version 67.0.3396.87. I’m running the below code; however,
...               the browser does not open in the desired language (fr-ca or ja).
...               https://robotframework.slack.com/messages/@U6SDCR92S
...
...               Reference page:
...               https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities
...
...               Firefox:
...               "intl": "accept_languages": "pt-PT,pt,en,en-us"
...               Accept-Language: pt-PT,pt;q=0.8,en;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.3
Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers
Force Tags        lang_test
Library           SeleniumLibrary
*** Test Cases ***
Set Chrome to fr-ca
    Switch language For Chrome    https://www.wikipedia.org/    fr-ca
    Sleep    3 seconds
    Capture Page Screenshot
    [Teardown]    Close Browser

Set Chrome to ja
    Switch language For Chrome    https://www.wikipedia.org/    ja
    Sleep    3 seconds
    Capture Page Screenshot
    [Teardown]    Close Browser

Set Chrome to pt-pt
    Switch language For Chrome    https://www.wikipedia.org/    pt-PT
    Sleep    3 seconds
    Capture Page Screenshot
    [Teardown]    Close Browser

*** Keywords ***
Switch language For Chrome
    [Arguments]    ${url}    ${locale}
    [Documentation]    Starts a Chrome Browser with specified locale
    ${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --lang\=${locale}
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    user-agent\=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1309.0 Safari/537.17
    Create webDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
    &{prefs}=    Create Dictionary    intl.accept_languages=${locale},en,en-us
    Call Method    ${options}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
    GoTo    ${url}
```